# Datatables search,show entries, pagination removes all the data and needs to reload page

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

[image]I have a populated datatable that shows data entries 0 to 0 of 0 entries, also along with search and sort, it removes the whole data and needs the page to be reloaded so that data can be seen again. Any help would be appreciated.

tried putting "serverSide": true but it shows an error in datatable.

here is my datatable

```
<div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped" id="mydata">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>No.</th>
                                        <th>Session ID</th>
                                        <th>Username</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Last Login Time</th>
                                        <th>Last Login IP</th>
                                        <th>Login System</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="show_data">

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

and my ajax that displays the table body content

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           show_manager(); //call function show all product
    //function show all manager
    function show_manager(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'admin/managers',
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var html = '';
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    html += '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_ID+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_sessID+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_username+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_fname+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_status+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_lastlogintime+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_lastloginIP+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_loginsystem+'</td>'+
                            '<td style="text-align:right;">'+
                                '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm manager_edit" data-emid="'+data[i].m_ID+'" data-m_username="'+data[i].m_username+'" data-m_email="'+data[i].m_email+'" data-m_fname="'+data[i].m_fname+'" data-m_status="'+data[i].m_status+'">Edit</a>'+' '+
                                '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm manager_delete" data-dmid="'+data[i].m_ID+'">Delete</a>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                }
                $('#show_data').html(html);
                $('#mydata').dataTable(
                "order": [[0, "desc"]]     <------edited line--->
                 );


            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: In your case, using `serverSide` should be correct. Please follow [Server Side Configuration](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side), see the "Example Data" section and check if your response is in correct format.

Comment: I added an image at the top, that's my error when I turn serverside to true/false.

Comment: Did you check your response(from 'admin/managers') is in correct format? If yes, please post the response to see what happen.

Comment: I added the image response, it shows 2 id are being processed after I click delete button, but id=18 is not actually deleted. I also modified the code in my ajax(check commented line)